# Treating space as newline character in bash

Tags: bash

I have written a bash just to display the name of all the files of a given directory but when I am running this it breaking the file name which has spaces.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "give a source directory in the command line argument in order to rename the jpg file"
exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
exit 2
fi

if [ -d "$1" ]
then
for i in $(ls "$1")
do
echo "$i"
done
fi
```

I am getting the following thing when I run the bash script

```
21151991jatinkhurana_image
(co
py).jpg
24041991jatinkhurana_im
age.jpg
35041991jatinkhurana_image
.jpg
```

The thing that i have tried till now is resetting the IFS variable like IFS=$(echo -en "\t\n\0") but found no change....

If anyone know please help me.....

Comment: I do not post this as a reply as I am sure it is a duplicate question. Spaces in your files name are treated as items separator in the `for i in $(ls "$1")`, just put quotes `for i in "$(ls "$1")"`. Note: useless use of `ls`, use: `for i in "$1"/*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not loop through the result of `ls`. Parsing ls makes world worse (good read: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Instead, you can do make use of the `*`, that expands to the existing content in a given directory:

```
for file in /your/dir/*
do
   echo "this is my file: $file"
done
```

Using variables:

```
for file in $dir/*
do
   echo "this is my file: $file"
done
```