# Regular expression in bash not working

Tags: regex, bash

Is there any way in bash so that I can match the patter like that

```
[0-9]{8}.*.jpg
```

I have written the above for the following pattern match
"First 8 character should be digit and rest of them would be anything and end with .jpg"
but the above is not working. if I write in the below manner it's working

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*.jpg
```

Now suppose I want first 20 character must be digit should I repeat the [0-9] 20 times.. I think there is a better solution available which i don't know...

If anyone know please help....

Comment: Have you tried `=~`? And the regex can be `\d{8}.*\.jpg`. See [bash regex match](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF)

Comment: How are you trying to use it? Keep in mind that `bash` *only* recognizes regular expressions following the `=~` operator in a `[[ ... ]]` command; elsewhere your pattern is treated as a filename glob.

Comment: I'm surprised no answer here yet mentions bash's extglobs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah I studied it a little but then discarded because `find` together with regex seems to suffice. Now I see jm666 covers it with his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex in `find`:

```
find test -regextype posix-extended -regex "^[0-9]{8}.*.jpg$"
```

#### Test

```
$ touch test/12345678aaa.jpg
$ touch test/1234567aaa.jpg

$ find test -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[0-9]{8}.*"
test/12345678aaa.jpg
```

And if it is related to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620951/treating-space-as-newline-charactar-in-bash), you can use:

```
for file in $(find test -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[0-9]{8}.*")
do
   echo "my file is $file"
done
```

---

If you create directories and files in them, more matchings can appear:

```
$ mkdir test/123456789.dir
$ touch test/123456789.dir/1234567890.jpg
```

You can filter by `-type f`, so that you just get files:

```
$ find test -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[0-9]{8}.*"
test/12345678aaa.jpg
test/123456789.dir/1234567890.jpg
```

And/or specify the depth of the `find`, so that it does not contain subdirectories:

```
$ find test -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[0-9]{8}.*"
test/12345678aaa.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to generate a list of filenames from a regular expression.  You can do that, but not directly from Bash as far as I know.  Instead, use `find`:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/[0-9]{8}.*\.jpg' -depth 1
```

Something like that works on my Mac OS X system; on Linux the `.` for current directory is optional, or you can specify a different directory to search in.  I added `-depth 1` to avoid descending into subdirectories.

Comment: @JatinKhurana, it escapes the literal `.` in `.jpg`, which otherwise matches any character. You could leave it out if writing the extension as `[.]jpg`, which is how I would do it.

Comment: sorry for late reply(was busy in my exam)... but I was asking for the first one */[0-9]... in the previous ....

Comment: `.*/` matches the directory part of the paths.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answer.

Bash's filename exapnsion *patterns* ( called *globbing* ) has it's own rules. They're exists in two forms:

- simple globbing
- extended globbing (if you have enabled `shopts -s extglob`

You can read about the both *rules* for example [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC38). (3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching)

You should remember, **the globbing rules aren't the traditional regular expressions** (as you probably know for `grep` or `sed` and such), and especially they're not the perl's (extended) regular expressions.

So, if you want use filename expansion (aka globbing) you're stuck with the above two (simple/extended) *pattern* rules. Of course, bash knows regular expressions, but *not* for filename-expansion (globbing).

So, you can for example do the next:

```
shopt -s globstar        #if you haven't already enabled - for the ** expansion
regex="[0-9]{8}.*\.jpg"
for file in ./**/*.jpg   #will match all *.jpg recusrively (globstar)
do
    #try the regex matching
    [[ $file =~ $regex ]] || continue  #didn't match

    #matched! - do something with the file
    echo "the $file has at least 8 digits"
done
```

or you can use, the `find` command with the built-in regex matching rules (see other answers), or the `grep` with perl-like regexes, such:

```
find somewhere -type f -name \*.jpg -maxdepth 1 -print0 | grep -zP '/\d{8}.*.jpg'
```

The speed: for the large trees the `find` is faster. At least on my notebook, where:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file
do
    echo "$file"
done < <(find ~/Pictures -name \*.JPG -print0 | grep -zP 'P\d{4}.*\.JPG')
```

runs `real  0m1.593s`, and the

```
regex="P[0-9]{4}.*\.JPG"
for file in ~/Pictures/**/*.JPG
do
    [[ $file =~ $regex ]] || continue  #didn't match

    echo "$file"
done
```

runs `real  0m3.628s` seconds.

On the small trees, IMHO is better to use the builting bash regexes. (maybe, I prefer it because i like the `./**/*.ext` expansion, and got all filenames correctly inside the variable, regardless of spaces and like, without the care about the `-print0` and `read -d $'\0;` and such...)

Comment: Very very good approach, with good explanation, references and comparisons! Picky question: what do you prefer? I like the way `find` handles it and I would go for it in case it is just a matter of listing files.